# How to verify that a superclass' constructor is being called

Tags: java, unit-testing

Let's say there is a super-class

```
class SuperClass {
    SuperClass(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    SuperClass() {
        this.foo = new DefaultFoo();
    }
}
```

And there's a sub-class

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
     SubClass(Foo foo) {
        super(foo);
    }
}
```

The class under test is `SubClass`. I want to verify that `SubClass'` constructor is indeed invoking it's superclass' non-empty constructor. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you really need to question the Java Language Specification, you can insert a `logger.debug(...)` line in that constructor.

Comment: I thought you are actually doing this, what you want.. Do you want to test whether it works or not??

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I want to write a unit test case that verifies that `SubClass'` constructor calls `SuperClass'` constructor.

Comment: Depending on problem You could make default constructor private and expose it through factory method.

Comment: @Lalit: please give me a scenario where your test would fail. If there is none, then there's no need for a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with  jmockit ( http://jmockit.googlecode.com )  by mocking superclass.  Here is example

( from: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jmockit-users/O-w9VJm4xOc )

```
public class TestClassUnderTest { 

     public class ClassUnderTest extends BaseClassForClassUnderTest 
     { 
        public ClassUnderTest(ISomeInterface si) 
        { 
           super(si); 
         } 
         //... 
      } 
@Test 
public void testSuperConstructorCall() 
{ 
    final ISomeInterface si = new ISomeInterface() 
    { 
    }; 

    Mockit.setUpMock(BaseClassForClassUnderTest.class, new Object() { 
        @Mock 
        public void $init(ISomeInterface si_param) 
        { 
            assertNotNull(si_param); 
            assertTrue(si_param == si); 
        } 
    }); 

    ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest(si); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I would test this via the super constructors side effects. e.g. does it set particular fields or change behaviour ?

Note that the implementation of your class should really be shielded from the tests. So you're only interested in how it affects the constructed entity. Otherwise if/when you refactor your class hierarchy you'd have to change your tests, whereas you need them to remain the same in order to perform a *regression*.

Comment: I agree with you that implementation of a class should not be influenced by its tests. But I do not understand how a test would be independent of the implementation of the class. Changing a class' inheritance hierarchy is a rather intimate change for the class. Is the test case not supposed to get impacted with such a change?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Your tests should be testing the behaviour of your class and the results it gives in response to inputs. It shouldn't be concerned with the intricacies of how it does it. If the component uses complex functionality then perhaps you should extract *that* into separate classes to ease unit testing of that, but the unit test testing your top-level functionality should be as unconcerned as possible wrt. implementation

Comment: I understand what you mean. This is a how-would-I-do-if-I-were-to kind of question. Konstantin's answer provides a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check that from a unit test, you can simply create a `Foo` instance, pass it to the `SubClass` constructor and then check whether `instance.getFoo()` returns the exact same reference.

Comment: Currently I am doing exactly that. But it requires the method `getFoo()` in the `SuperClass`. What if it isn't? I just want to verify the behaviour of my class calling a superclass' constructor.

Comment: A cheap workaround would be to have that method package private... But the super call is performed by static binding (as any other form of overloading); so you don't need to check what happens at runtime, since you should know what gets called at compile-time. It seems to me like testing that `new String("")` actually calls the expected `String` constructor... If I doubted that, I would switch to another programming language in no time.

Comment: `String` is a class provided by library. I do not want to verify the behaviour of whole JVM. The class under test i.e. `SubClass` is supposed to call its superclass with the `Foo` instance it was passed in the constructor. If some developer deletes this call to superclass, the superclass will then use a `DefaultFoo`. I want the test case to be able to fail when this happens.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a boolean field in your superclass and set it "true" within the non-empty constructor, and thus making it "true" when the non-empty constructor is called. Check the status of that boolean instance field for the corresponding object to know which constructor has been invoked.